# Got a runtime error but the actual operation executed succesfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm on the presence of a very weird behavior.

Consider the following scenario:

```
>>> t = ([1],)
>>> t[0]
[1]
>>> t[0] += [2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t[0]
[1, 2]
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does `t[0] += [2]` fails?
2. Why was the list updated if the assignment failed?

As far as I'm aware this is happening on both Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Comment: You have a mutable type within an immutable container.  What you are doing is equivalent to `t[0].extend([2])`, then `t[0] = t[0]`